# How can we insert row after row from flat file to OLEdb destnation db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a flat file with many rows and columns separated by delimiter(|). Before inserting row into destination I have to be check whether record is already existed or not by matching some columns, if it is there I have to add only amount field value into that record and then it has to come for next row for inserting.

I tried with Lookup transformation, then I realized the match case works only when table having already records, if the table is empty we can't do with lookup  because the flat file records inserting batch wise. If the table is empty the whole rows comes no matching case then all rows gets inserted db. but I have to be filtered the flat file record so each row before inserting.

```
Flat file row:
Row1= 100|10.35|abc|10/2018
Row2= 100|15.35|abc|10/2018
Row3= 101|20.00|xyz|10/2018
```

target to be loaded into oledb dest db;

```
Row1= 100|25.70|abc|10/2018  (25.70 == Row1 amount + Row2 amount)
Row3= 101|20.00|xyz|10/2018`enter code here`
```

Comment: You can do all sorts of things in SSIS, but I wouldnt. Personally I would always load the whole file into a staging table, then do the rest in sql queries. I find it much easier to verify that I got the whole file into sql and find it is much easier to manage that way. Of course SSIS fans might disagree, so I'd wait for a second opinion!

Comment: I would load the entire data to a temp table (maybe using an SSIS package), then group the info and insert it on its final destination, and lastly drop/clear the temp table.

Comment: I think adding unique (composite as checking on multiple column) constrains can do this. First add constrains on your necessary columns in the table and then insert bulk rows from the flat file. Automatically second and later duplicate rows should be failed while try to insert.

Comment: Use AggregateTransformation http://www.msbiguide.com/aggregate-transformation-in-ssis-2008r2-with-example/

Comment: Thanks,but I  shouldn't to add any key constraints in Sql table,the table is accessed by multiple users & and it having 50 columns with duplicate values @mkRabbani

Comment: Thanks @TomC @@M. Ruiz ,But i am still looking for some alternative task to do that instead of temp table,Currently i working RowCount task,will see that if will  have a luck.

Comment: Thanks @Yahfoufi. for your good suggestion.Aggregate is the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an aggregate transformation.

1. read using flat file source and '|' delimiter.
2. agg transform group on col1,3,4 and sum col2
3. load to table

Comment: Thank you very much @KeithL ,I have tested aggregate tranf. in my pc .It's working fine and the same i will apply in my project